# Why is my Android TextView not changing colour?

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a TextView as part of my Android Fragment that should be changing text colour when it changes the text, but although the text is changing as I expect, the colour is staying black, which is not actually any of the colours I want it to be.

The Fragment view looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/control"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/direction"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|top"
        android:text="" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Then the code that actually sets the value of the Textview - it is giving the compass direction and the idea is that if the phone is pointed more closely to the direction the colour of the text should change. The text does change, but the colour stays resolutely the same. I'm including every mention of the component from the whole class - a text search doesn't show it up anywhere else:

```
  private TextView directionView;

  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        directionView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.direction);
  }

  private void setDirection(AccurateDirection direction) {
        int directionColour = R.color.direction_approx;
        switch ( direction.getAccuracy()) {
           case AccurateDirection.ACCURACY_CLOSE:
                directionColour = R.color.direction_close;
                break;
            case AccurateDirection.ACCURACY_EXACT:
                directionColour = R.color.direction_exact;
                break;
        }
        directionView.setText(direction.getDirection());
        directionView.setTextColor(directionColour);
    }
```

Probably irrelevant, but the colours are like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="control_background">#FF40AA</color>
    <color name="black_overlay">#66000000</color>
    <color name="text_foreground">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="text_shadow">#000000</color>
    <color name="gps_unfixed">#FF0000</color>
    <color name="gps_fixed">#00AA33</color>
    <color name="direction_approx">#CCCCCC</color>
    <color name="direction_close">#EEEEEE</color>
    <color name="direction_exact">#CCFFCC</color>
  </resources>
```

What do I need to do to get the text changing colour when the content of the text changes?

Comment: This is very common error. From the [`TextView` doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor(int)): Do not pass a resource ID. To get a color value from a resource ID, call `Resources.getColor`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not working because `setTextColor(int)` [does not accept resource IDs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor(int)), which is what you are passing it:

You need to retrieve the color using the resource ID first, then pass that color to the `setTextColor` method. You can grab the color using the `ContextCompat` `getColor` method from the support library, as `Resources.getColor` has been deprecated (since API 23).

```
directionView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(directionColour));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `TextWatcher` and listen for changes for your `TextView` and thereby do whatever action you wish to do. A little quick example:

```
directionView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if(s.equals("helloOrSomethingElse")){
      directionView.setTextColor(ContexCompat.getColor(context, R.color.direction_exact));
   }

} 
});
```